# How to setup a calculated column for a choice column?

Tags: column

Ok i guess i'm doing formula wrong.

I have a choice column "Single"with two choices that i typed "Yes" and "No".

The second column "Album" is the calculated one and it's supposed to work like this:

If the "Single" is yes , then "Album" shows No
If the "Single" is no, then "Album" shows yes

What IF formula should i put into "Album" formula field?

If i try with True/False i always get only one answer doesn't matter what the "Single" shows.

Comment: Why not change the logic to one Choice Column with (text) options "Single" and "Album", simpler logic and gives you the future option of easily adding other delivery types

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following simple formula should work:

`=IF([Single]="Yes", "No", "Yes")`

Comment: Thank you that formula worked now even though i'm quite sure i've already tried that one, but the funny thing is when i entered your formula, saved the column and then entered column again, it said "=IF(Single="Yes","No","Yes")" - [ & ] have disappeared.